# Regex to match a string which does not contain a specific word next to the match string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have Text as below

```
 1. This is                678         897        999
    not a text which I want


   2. This is                 678         897        879
```

I have applied regex as

```
This\s*is\s*(\s+\d+){1,}(?: ){0,}[\r\n]+
```

Now what I want is match a string which does not have ***not*** next to the match string. I don't want the regex to match first string.

**EDIT**

Suppose I have 2 string as above and I applied regex then I found 2 match

```
This is                678         897        999
This is                 678         897        879
```

Upto this all is perfect but now I want regex which does not contain ***not(in first string)***, I want to match only 2nd string.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what is the criteria to match and not match

Comment: Try [`(?>This\s+is(?:\s+\d+)+ *)(?![\r\n]+\p{Zs}*not\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3eThis%5cs%2bis(%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cd%2b)%2b+*)(%3f!%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%5cp%7bZs%7d*not%5cb)&i=+1.+This+is++++++++++++++++678+++++++++897++++++++999%0d%0a++++not+a+text+which+I+want%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a+++2.+This+is+++++++++++++++++678+++++++++897++++++++879).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want regex which does not contain not(in first string), I want to match only 2nd string.

That means you should check if the `This is...` pattern is not followed by newline sequence + spaces* + `not` as a whole word *with backtracking disabled*. We can disable backtracking using *atomic group* in .NET:

```
(?>This\s+is(?:\s+\d+)+ *)(?![\r\n]+\p{Zs}*not\b)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3EThis%5Cs%2Bis(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B)%2B%20%2A)(%3F!%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%2Anot%5Cb)&i=%201.%20This%20is%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20678%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20897%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20999%0D%0A%20%20%20%20not%20a%20text%20which%20I%20want%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%202.%20This%20is%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20678%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20897%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20879)

Part 1 of the regex `This\s+is(?:\s+\d+)+ *` matches `This is` followed with one or more sequences of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more digits, then followed with zero or more spaces. The `(?>...)` prevent backtracking inside this part of the pattern. The lookahead `(?![\r\n]+\p{Zs}*not\b)` fails the match if the previously matched text is followed with the whitespaces followed with a whole word `not` (where `\b` stands for a word boundary).

Answer (score 3):

```
This\s*is\s*(\s+\d+){1,}(?: ){0,}(?:[\r\n]+|$)(?!not)
```

Just add `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/8